# Why does an electrical current have no effect on a stationary charge

Tags: electromagnetism

According to special relativity, a stationiary observer would observe a moving object as being shorter. So a moving current in a wire would appear to have a more dense amount of electrons for a stationary observer. Wouldn't this repel a stationary negative charge?

I was looking at a very similar stack exchange question but the explanation was to complex for me 
[current in wire + special relativity = magnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82821/current-in-wire-special-relativity-magnetism?rq=1)

Comment: This seems exactly the same as the question you link to, its not really clear what else one could add to the accepted answer there which is good. I could add a shorter answer but it would be a subset of that one.

Comment: The assumption that moving charges in a wire are moving at relativistic speeds is incorrect.  The drift speed for electrons in a wire that is carrying a "normal" amount of current is on the order of one meter per hour.  This is definitely NOT a relativistic speed.